# How to set table level write rights in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am wondering if in BigQuery is it possible to offer to a service user rights only to specific tables. How can I learn if in the instance that we use we have this feature enabled?
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls-intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the right documentation.

[BigQuery release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#June_04_2020) declare that

> BigQuery Table ACL is now available as a beta release.

It means your project should be able to use the feature by default.